# Wordpress contact form 7 отправка при выборе checkbox?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Есть форма на сайте в которой два текстовых поля имя и текст, у нее есть 4 чекбокса: телефон, телеграм, ватсап, email.

Как мне сделать что бы при выборе одного из чекбокса разные действия были? Если выбрал телефон, то просто форма отправлена, если телеграм то человека перекидывает после отправки формы по ссылке на телеграм, ватсап так же по ссылке на ватсап, а вот email надо чтобы человеку отправлялся автоответчик который я задал уже в админке. Как это сделать ?

Форма:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите где можно почитать или как реализовать спс?

Comment: Думаю тут надо на js-е смотреть, какой чекбокс выбран и после события отправки формы что-нибудь с этим делать. Про события CF7 можно почитать тут https://contactform7.com/dom-events/

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться

Comment: Эмм.. А нафига перекидывать в **другое приложение**? Какой в этом смысл? А если  вдруг человек заполняет на десктопе, где нет ни телеги ни ватсапа - уверен что хочешь доставить неудобств?

Comment: ТАк человек сам нажимая чекбокс выбирает что ему удобно, а этом и смысл выбора

Comment: Человек выбирает куда получить ответ. Который НЕ МОМЕНТАЛЬНЫЙ.  И вряд ли ждет что после отправки форумы из браузера у него начнёт запускаться приложуха. Вот нафига она в данный момент? Я бы лично был раздражен таким неожиданным поведением. Хочешь запустить приложуху - установи ссылку на запуск. а не после отправки формы. Можно эти ссылки показать после отправки на той же страницу.

Answer (score 1):

а решил все еще намного проще

```js
document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {
        if ('22' == event.detail.contactFormId) {
            if ($('#mc2 ').is(":checked")) {
                location = 'https://t.me/residenciaes';
            } else if ($('#mc3 ').is(":checked")) {
                location = 'https://wa.me/message/M5CXS2OSK46PD1';
            }
        }
    }, false);
```

2 чекбокса редирект после отправки, а 2 по дефолту просто отправка

Answer (score 0):

Кому интересно может пригодится, вот нашел решение через Хуки

https://help-wp.ru/contact-form-7-wpcf7_before_send_mail/